# Is there any way to quick switch between first and third person perspective in skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'm looking for a way to quickly switch between first and third person perspective in skyrim.  I've learnt that you can press the F key and this will switch, but there is a delay, is there anyway to speed this up, or swap instantly?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can speed up the transition speed between first person and third person by adding the following lines to your `Skyrim.ini` file under the `[Camera]` section:

```
fMouseWheelZoomSpeed=60.0000
f1st3rdSwitchDelay=0.9500
iHorseTransitionMillis=001
```

This will affect changing perspective both by using the keyboard binding (default F) and the mouse wheel.

The `Skyrim.ini` file should be located in `%USERPROFILE%\Documents\My Games\Skyrim` rather than in the steamapps folder, if the file doesn't exist you should simply be able to create a file named `Skyrim.ini` in this location.

Comment: I knew somewhere out there would be a genius with the correct config settings :-) thanks very much I'll try it tomorrow :-)

Comment: Okay so can confirm this works. BUT to anyone like myself using Mod Organizer be sure to edit the Skyrim.ini through the "INI Editor" drop-down at the top of Mod Organizer!